# Neglect Blank from fact table Measure dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a situation in which fact table has more key values than in my dim table ( it is ok). my problem is that when i am trying to calculate sum, of values from fact table i get a row called (blank), anyone can try to explain get sample of how to get rid of that blank row? thank you

I attach the sample and a data-model. The Measure is simple `SumVAL:=SUM(FACT[VALUE])`

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xhhe.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a basic filter under Visual Level Filter for your table in your Power BI Report Design like below, uncheck "blank" checkbox only.

[image]

EDIT (WITH DAX): I have created a Measure Column with the code below and used it in my table:

```
MeasureColumn = SELECTCOLUMNS(NATURALINNERJOIN(Sheet1,Sheet2),"newcolumn",sumx(NATURALINNERJOIN(Sheet1,Sheet2),Sheet1[value]))
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Why it does not work for you? Maybe I misunderstood your question? @ygaft

Comment: My model has about 70+ measures and lots of reports, some reports are not filtered on a row level (save memory), for instance I have pivots with only a measures at values (no row metrics). When no filter applied, the measure represents wrong total value. Because of that I wanted to filter the measure itself by dax